# Strange behaviour when constructing an object (in C++)

Tags: c++, object

once again (a perhaps trivial) problem ist driving me nuts. I have just spent 4 hours trying to find out what is goint on but was unsuccessfull. This is why once again I turn to the community to ask for help.

After reading the intial answeres and doing some more debugging I had to edit the question:

```
class A{ 
  friend class B;
  int someMember;
  void setA(some paremeters);
};

class B{
  public: 
    A someA;
    B(some parameters){
        someA.setA(some parameters);
        std::cout<<someA.someMemeber; 
    }
};
```

Working with the debugger has shown me that someA.setA(some parameters) actually does what it is supposed to - it assings the correct values to A's memebers. Still after leaving A the assigned values seem to go out of scope and thus someA.someMember outputs sth. like -9.345345e+ etc. - meaning that the member has not been intialized despite the fact that I actually checked and someMemer was assined the propper value.

Has anybody encountered something like this before ?

Comment: This might not solve the problem, but use initializer lists: `B(int a) : someA(a) {}`

Comment: `B(int ina){someA.seta(a);}` I suppose it should be `B(int a)...` ? If you don't post code that actually can be used to reproduce the problem, it's very hard for people to help you.

Comment: Also, your code has tons of syntax errors. Please post compile-able code that demonstrates your problem. http://sscce.org/

Comment: I did the least I could to get your code to compile and it works: http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=23a6f3c431c7df39e7838023a57629c0

Comment: @ Pubby - I am sorry for the syntax errors. C++ is still somewhat new to me ...

Comment: @ Adrei Tita - the actual code is long and encompasses quite a lot of modules but I will try to provide a better example.

Answer (score 1):

A faulty implementation of `seta` or `geta` can easily cause this to happen - assuming you meant `void printa(){cout<<someA.geta();}` instead of `void printa(){cout<<A.geta();}`.

For example, `seta` doesn't actually set the member. It could be either empty, or a simple rookie mistake could be:

```
void seta(int x)
{
   int a = x;  //doesn't set the member, but a local variable
}
```

Comment: I already checked that and so far as I could see the setting was done correctly. Somehwo the members seem to become out of scope as soon as the setting ist done. I have no idea why ...

Answer (score 1):

You use `int ina` as the constructor parameter of `B`. But inside, you use `someA.seta(a);` to set the field value.

But what you really want to use is `someA.seta(ina);` in order to use the constructor parameter value to initialize 'a'.